# Google Sheet Scripts to Import Range: Error "You do not have permission to access it."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

TLDR: I need to import a range of cells from a separate google sheet using a scsript, but am being told I do not have access to the other sheet(I'm sure the ID is right). I don't know why I don't have access to the other sheet. If anyone knows a simple script to do this that would be great. Please help!

Hi everyone, I had been using importrange to pull data from other google sheets into my master sheet, but was experiencing the never-ending loading times that others have previously complained about. I've never used scripts before and so don't really know what I'm doing.

Within the destination google sheet, I created the following script but get this error: "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it."

```
function UpdateRange(ID, source_sheet, source_range, destination_sheet_name) {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ID))
    .getSheetByName(source_sheet)
    .getRange(source_range)
    .getValues();
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName(destination_sheet_name)
    .getRange(1, 22, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
}

UpdateRange("1Rt***_tRbs", "Revenue By Category", "E2:M9", "Sheet33");
```

***used to anonymize origin sheet ID

I don't understand how I don't have access to the sheet  even though I'm the one who created it in the first place. How do I get access to the sheet or what else I can do to import this range. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be that you do not have permission to access the Drive Folder location where the file is stored?

Comment: Hi Aleister! No, I definitely have access to both files. I created both of them and edit both frequently.

Comment: I take back what I said. Though I have access to the files, Scripts does not.

Comment: Alrighty, anything I/we can do to help ?

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance, you could try simplifying:

```
SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ID))...
```

to just:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID)...
```

Both approaches should work fine, but then you avoid using the DriveApp API which might require some different permissions than just the Spreadsheet one.

Comment: Hi Dustin! Thanks for your help. I am not longer getting the original error, but now I get the following in a later line: 
TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 4, file "Code")
This seems to indicate that it's not actually accessing the sheet. How do I figure out whats going on here?

Comment: Hi! You're using two, fairly long "chained" method calls (ie, calling `thing.method().method().method()`.) That makes it harder to understand bugs like that. I would try breaking those calls into separate statements, and maybe logging the intermediate results. For example: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID); Logger.log(ss); var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(); Logger.log(sheet);` That kind of thing.